# Sublime Text 3: How to install specific version of package

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin, package-control

I'm installing this package via package control but it's not choosing the latest one.

It installs version 1.5.3 but i want 1.5.6. Is there any way to declare the version number explicitly while installing?

[image]

Comment: what package are you trying to install?

Comment: Laravel Blade Highlighter: https://goo.gl/o8529K

Comment: @ZaynAli please don't use URL shorteners. People deserve to see what site they're about to visit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at [`packages.json`](https://github.com/Medalink/laravel-blade/blob/master/packages.json), you'll see that the two versions correlate to two different version of Sublime Text. 1.5.3 is for ST2 and ST3 builds less than or equal to 3083. 1.5.6 is for builds 3084 and greater. This is because 1.5.6 uses the new [`.sublime-syntax`](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/syntax.html) format, which was introduced in Build 3084. However, to get access to these new [development builds](https://sublimetext.com/3dev), you must have a [license](https://www.sublimetext.com/buy).

Comment: Ohh yes. I got it. Thank you @MattDMo :)

Comment: @ZaynAli is there a reason you unaccepted the answer?

Comment: No @MattDMo. I mistakenly clicked it while inspecting the UI of that green tick mark. Sorry about that.